# nginx rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite

I have the following mod_rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(host)\.doamin\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /magento/$1 [L]
```

I need that to work in nginx and I've been slamming my head against the wall to make it work

Thanks!

UPDATE!

Here is a better explanation of what I'm trying to do

```
 store1.domain.com
 store2.domain.com
```

so a user can go into store1.domain.com/products/ and the url will stay
there

We do this in apache like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(host)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /magento/$1 [L]
```

We also have a dns catchall that will send all *.domain.com to a default
apache vhost. I'm slamming my head against the wall to get it working in
nginx to keep the hostname the same but behind the scenes rewrite the
domain for magento to parse.

Here is what I have but it just keeps appending /magento/magento/magento
to the end till it kills the loop

```
    if ($http_host !~ "^www.domain\.com$") {
        rewrite ^.+ http://$http_host/magento/$uri last;
        break;
    }
```

The problem with the above is it keeps rewritting it as

```
store1.domain.com/magento/
store1.domain.com/magento/magento/
store1.domain.com/magento/magento/magento/ and so on
```

Here is a error log for it

```
2009/11/03 15:40:26 [error] 22347#0: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/magento//magento//magento//magento//magento//magento//magento//magento//magento//magento//magento//catalogsearch/advanced/result/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: laptop, request: "GET /catalogsearch/advanced/result/?featured=1 HTTP/1.1", host: "store1.domain.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name *.domain.com ;
    rewrite ^.+ httр://$host/magento/$uri last;
    break;
}
```

**UPD:**
You also can exclude hostnames and already done redirects via location+if+regex inside `server {}` section

```
location !~ \/magento\/
{
    if ($host !~ "^(www|host)\.domain\.com$")
    {
    // Here goes your rewrite
    }
}
```

PS. I think this could be done more sexy using 2 `server {}` blocks, but I'm too lazy to think about it now =)

Comment: that got me 50% of the way there. I need it to ignore www.domain.com and host.domain.com and keep the url if you go to store1.domain.com/products/ it doesn't get redirected to domain.com/magento/products  i need to pass the uri to /magento/ and keep the hostname there

Comment: Check now. Is it suitable for you?

Comment: Thanks.. its getting there.. I updated my post to better describe my situation. thanks for the help

Comment: Author of nginx strongly disapproves constructs like 

    if ($host !~ ... )

Don't bother with apache rewrites.  Just state your problem in simple terms.  AFAIU, you need:

www.domain.com/anything stays the same

store1.domain.com/anything rewrites to store1.domain.com/magento/anything

am I right?   Is that all there is?

Comment: You need to redirect every subdomain except host and www. I've already said that the right move will be making 2 `server {}` directives one matching `~ ^(www|host)\.domain\.com$` and other `!~ ^(www|host)\.domain\.com$` but it'll be less customizeble i.e. you can't add any other domain to such configuration.